# How to resolve sql query In pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyspark

I am new to sql query and having a small problem , here i want to find "top 3 venues which hosted most number of eliminator matches" but I think my sql is wrong how to get this done?
(I'm using jupiter notebook and pyspark)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf

pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data2 = pd.read_csv('ipl_matches.csv')

data2

#Most number of eliminator matches
eliminator = data2[data2.eliminator == 'Y']
eliminator

##I'm having problem in this query##
q = """SELECT venue_id, eliminator 
       FROM eliminator """

names = pysqldf(q)
names
```

[image: Here is the eliminator data]

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

See if this query works for you:

```
q=""" SELECT venue_id
    FROM eliminator group by venue_id order by count(venue_id) desc LIMIT 3"""
```

Answer (score 0):

use this query :

```
q = """SELECT venue_id, eliminator FROM eliminator order by venue_id desc limit 3 """
```

this will give you last 3 biggest `venue_id` in descending mode